# PHP get the field values inside a duplicated div using jQuery clone method in form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, clone

in my codeigniter view, I've a table row which duplicates when a button is clicked using jQuery clone method. My task is to get the field values inside the duplicated row when the form is submitted.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function duplicate() {    
var original = document.getElementById('service');
var rows = original.parentNode.rows;
var i = rows.length - 1;
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
clone.id = "duplic" + (i); // there can only be one element with an ID
clone.name = "duplic" + (i); 
original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, rows[i]);
}
</script>

    <div class="portlet-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
<?php

$attrib = array (
        'class' => 'addcomplaint',
        'id' => 'addcomplaint',
        'role' => 'form' 
);
echo form_open ( "vehicle/regcomplaint", $attrib );
?>
<!-- COMPLAINT INFO TAB -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
            <table style="padding: 0px;">
                <tr id="service">
                    <td class="form-group col-md-6" style="padding: 0px;">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-6" style="padding: 0px;">Complaint Description</label> 
                        <select name="complainttype" id="select2_sample4" class="select2 form-control">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>select complaint type</option>
                            <option value="Complaint Type 1">Complaint Type 1</option>
                            <option value="Complaint Type 2">Complaint Type 2</option>
                            <option value="Complaint Type 3">Complaint Type 3</option>
                            <option value="Complaint Type 4">Complaint Type 4</option>
                            <option value="Complaint Type 5">Complaint Type 5</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-6" style="padding: 0px;">Work Hours</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="workhours" id="workhours" style="padding-right: 0px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" id="addmore" class="btn green" style="float: right; margin-right: 15px; margin-top: 20px;" onclick="duplicate()">
                            Add Complaint <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="margiv-top-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn green-haze" value="Submit" name="submit"> <a href="#" class="btn default">Cancel </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END COMPLAINT INFO TAB -->
<?php echo form_close();?> 
</div>
</div>
```

When I try submitting the form, I'm getting only original fields, not the duplicated fields. Can anyone help me to get the values in duplicated field also. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the cloned fields have the same name as the originals? If so, you will need to modify your code to create unique names for each field to avoid overwriting earlier values with later ones.

Comment: No the duplicated fields have different name

Answer (score 0):

In these scenarios its often easier to give the field names based on an array – for example:

```
<p>Recommend a friend:</p>
<input type="text" name="recommended_friend[]"/>
```

It just means that server side you can do something along the lines of:

```
foreach($_POST['recommended_friend'] as $recommend){
    // deal with the input field
}
```

This will work with one of the fields, or hundreds of them

Comment: When I use field names based on an array and foreach loop, it gives me error `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: try `$recommended_friend  = $_POST['recommended_friend']; foreach($recommended_friend as $recommend){`